# Arbitrary precision arithmetic with Ruby

Tags: ruby, math, bignum, arbitrary-precision

How the heck does Ruby do this? Does Jörg or anyone else know what's happening behind the scenes?

Unfortunately I don't know C very well so [`bignum.c`](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/tree/trunk/bignum.c#L1816-1848) is of little help to me. I was just kind of curious it someone could explain (in plain English) the theory behind whatever miracle algorithm its using.

```
irb(main):001:0> 999**999
```

> 368063488259223267894700840060521865838338232037353204655959621437025609300472231530103873614505175218691345257589896391130393189447969771645832382192366076536631132001776175977932178658703660778465765811830827876982014124022948671975678131724958064427949902810498973271030787716781467419524180040734398996952930832508934116945966120176735120823151959779536852290090377452502236990839453416790640456116471139751546750048602189291028640970574762600185950226138244530187489211615864021135312077912018844630780307462205252807737757672094320692373101032517459518497524015120165166724189816766397247824175394802028228160027100623998873667435799073054618906855460488351426611310634023489044291860510352301912426608488807462312126590206830413782664554260411266378866626653755763627796569082931785645600816236891168141774993267488171702172191072731069216881668294625679492696148976999868715671440874206427212056717373099639711168901197440416590226524192782842896415414611688187391232048327738965820265934093108172054875188246591760877131657895633586576611857277011782497943522945011248430439201297015119468730712364007639373910811953430309476832453230123996750235710787086641070310288725389595138936784715274150426495416196669832679980253436807864187160054589045664027158817958549374490512399055448819148487049363674611664609890030088549591992466360050042566270348330911795487647045949301286614658650071299695652245266080672989921799342509291635330827874264789587306974472327718704306352445925996155619153783913237212716010410294999877569745287353422903443387562746452522860420416689019732913798073773281533570910205207767157128174184873357050830752777900041943256738499067821488421053870869022738698816059810579221002560882999884763252161747566893835178558961142349304466506402373556318707175710866983035313122068321102457824112014969387225476259342872866363550383840720010832906695360553556647545295849966279980830561242960013654529514995113584909050813015198928283202189194615501403435553060147713139766323195743324848047347575473228198492343231496580885057330510949058490527738662697480293583612233134502078182014347192522391449087738579081585795613547198599661273567662441490401862839817822686573112998663038868314974259766039340894024308383451039874674061160538242392803580758232755749310843694194787991556647907091849600704712003371103926967137408125713631396699343733288014254084819379380555174777020843568689927348949484201042595271932630685747613835385434424807024615161848223715989797178155169951121052285149157137697718850449708843330475301440373094611119631361702936342263219382793996895988331701890693689862459020775599439506870005130750427949747071390095256759203426671803377068109744629909769176319526837824364926844730545524646494321826241925107158040561607706364484910978348669388142016838792902926158979355432483611517588605967745393958061959024834251565197963477521095821435651996730128376734574843289089682710350244222290017891280419782767803785277960834729869249991658417000499998999

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple: it does it the same way *you* do, ever since first grade. Except it doesn't compute in base 10, it computes in base 4 billion (and change).

Think about it: with *our* number system, we can only represent numbers from `0` to `9`. So, how can we compute `6+7` without overflowing? Easy: we *do* actually overflow! We cannot represent the result of `6+7` as a number between `0` and `9`, but we *can* overflow to the next place and represent it as *two* numbers between `0` and `9`: 3×10<sup>0</sup> + 1×10<sup>1</sup>. If you want to add two numbers, you add them digit-wise from the right and overflow ("carry") to the left. If you want to multiply two numbers, you have to multiply every digit of one number individually with the other number, then add up the intermediate results.

BigNum arithmetic (this is what this kind of arithmetic where the numbers are bigger than the native machine numbers is usually called) works basically the same way. Except that the base is not 10, and its not 2, either – it's the size of a native machine integer. So, on a 32 bit machine, it would be base 2<sup>32</sup> or 4 294 967 296.

Specifically, in Ruby `Integer` is actually an abstract class that is never instianted. Instead, it has two subclasses, `Fixnum` and `Bignum`, and numbers automagically migrate between them, depending on their size. In MRI and YARV, Fixnum can hold a 31 or 63 bit signed integer (one bit is used for tagging) depending on the native word size of the machine. In JRuby, a Fixnum can hold a full 64 bit signed integer, even on an 32 bit machine.

The simplest operation is adding two numbers. And if you look at the implementation of `+` or rather `bigadd_core` in YARV's [bignum.c](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/trunk/bignum.c#L1816-1848), it's not *too* bad to follow. I can't read C either, but you can cleary see how it loops over the individual digits.

Comment: You have such a good way of explaining things. Thank you for all of your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You could read the source for [`bignum.c`](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/bignum.c?view=markup)...

At a very high level, without going into *any* implementation details, `bignum`s are calculated "by hand" like you used to do in grade school.  Now, there are certainly *many* optimizations that can be applied, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know C very well. I was just kind of curious it someone could explain (in plain English) the theory behind whatever miracle algorithm its using.

Comment: @macek: that "miracle algorithm" is the same one you learned in first grade. Well, okay, there's all kinds of crazy optimizations one can do, but it's essentially the same. Think about it: *you* can multiply `23*45` even though our number system only goes from `0` to `9` by simply using *multiple* numbers. The same can be done on the computer, except with a number system that goes from `0` to `4294967296`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of the implementation details so I'll cover how a basic Big Number implementation would work.

Basically instead of relying on CPU "integers" it will create it's own using multiple CPU integers. To store arbritrary precision, well lets say you have 2 bits. So the current integer is 11. You want to add one. In normal CPU integers, this would roll over to 00

But, for big number, instead of rolling over and keeping a "fixed" integer width, it would allocate another bit and simulate an addition so that the number becomes the correct 100.

Try looking up how binary math can be done on paper. It's very simple and is trivial to convert to an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**Beaconaut APICalc 2** just released on Jan.18, 2011, which is an arbitrary-precision integer calculator for bignum arithmetic, cryptography analysis and number theory research......

http://www.beaconaut.com/forums/default.aspx?g=posts&t=13

Answer (score 0):

It uses the Bignum class

```
irb(main):001:0> (999**999).class
=> Bignum
```

[Rdoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Bignum.html) is available of course